# Is there a way to use a single controller and single generic JPARepository to handle multiple entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The product I'm working on has more than 80 lookup tables and each with their own CRUD operations.

I don't want to create separate controllers and JPARepositories for each of those models but I'd like to use a single controller and a generic JPARepository to handle all the lookup table entities.

Controller is a @RestController and it accepts json data and needs to have 4 operations namely LIST, GET, POST and PUT. Since the json data format is the same as there is only one table involved and no relations whatsoever, I think it must be possible achieve this in Sprint Hibernate.

Appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/lookup/{tableName}")
public class LookupController {

@Autowired
private GenericRepository repository;

@GetMapping
public List<?> list(@PathVariable String tableName) {
    return repository.findAll(tableName);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Object get(@PathVariable String tableName, @PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(tableName, id);
}

@PutMapping("/{id}")
public void update(@PathVariable String tableName, @PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Object entity) {
    repository.save(tableName, entity);
}

@GetMapping("/findBy/{property}/{value}")
public List<?> findByProperty(@PathVariable String tableName, @PathVariable String property, @PathVariable String value) {
    return repository.findByProperty(tableName, property, value);
}
```

}

```
@Repository
public class GenericRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<?> findAll(String tableName) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + tableName + " e").getResultList();
}

public Object findById(String tableName, Long id) {
    return entityManager.find(tableName, id);
}

public void save(String tableName, Object entity) {
    entityManager.merge(entity);
}

public List<?> findByProperty(String tableName, String property, String value) {
    String query = "SELECT e FROM " + tableName + " e WHERE e." + property + " = :value";
    TypedQuery<?> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Object.class);
    typedQuery.setParameter("value", value);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Above reference is one way or generic entity class that can be used to represent all your lookup tables. And create a generic repository that extends JPA repository and inject it in controller and use it to perform various CRUD operations for lookup entities.

```
public interface GenericRepository <T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
```

}

Comment: Thanks butterCup. I will try this approach and will let you know how this goes. Thanks once again!

Comment: This actually works but I had to make few changes in GenericRepository especially in entityManager.createQuery where I had to add a second parameter (Class object) for successful mapping of rows. Thanks anyways for the pointer! Cheers